# Deep links when tab is removed

Tags: microsoft-teams

When sharing deep links to a team-scoped tab in a channel, you can provide an optional `subEntityWebURL`. When the tab is removed, I was expecting to have the deep links open the `subEntityWebURL` (because the tab is gone), but instead, nothing seems to happen (i.e. all the deep links into the tab are dead until the tab is added again). Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the current expectation.  I'll escalate the need for a better fallback to engineering.